# How do I access web-server on my local VM from a different host machine on different network?

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I want to access a web-server running on my local Vagrant VM on say network A from a different host machine's browser connected to network B. I have used following in my vagrant file and forwarding ports accordingly :

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.59.49"
```

It's working fine if I try to access the server from my local machine's browser but not from a machine connected to a different network.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can open and forward your 80 port from local machine to vm or other port like 8080.
2. You can put the VM in the same network with your machine via DHCP or give it a static IP
3. Create a VPN with all the machines from where you wannt to access you VM